# Implementing a copy constructor for a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am trying to implement a copy constructor for a linked list with c++. Would it be possible to first copy the elements of the linked list in to an array and then make the `array[i] = list`? (`list` is taken as a parameter.)

```
template <typename Type>
Single_list<Type>::Single_list( Single_list<Type> const &list ):
list_head( 0 ),
list_tail( 0 ),
node_count( 0 ) {

    // enter your implementation here
    for(int i = 0; i < node_count; i++){
    *tmp_array = new array[node_count];
    tmp_array[i] = list;


}
```

Sorry in advance, I am new to coding..

Okay here it is:

```
template <typename Type>
class Single_list {
    private:
        Single_node<Type> *list_head;
        Single_node<Type> *list_tail;
        int node_count;


    public:
        Single_list();
        Single_list( Single_list const & );
        ~Single_list();

        // Accessors

        int size() const;
        bool empty() const;

        Type front() const;
        Type back() const;

        Single_node<Type> *head() const;
        Single_node<Type> *tail() const;

        int count( Type const & ) const;

        // Mutators

        void swap( Single_list & );
        Single_list &operator = ( Single_list const & );

        void push_front( Type const & );
        void push_back( Type const & );

        Type pop_front();

        int erase( Type const & );

    // Friends

    template <typename T>
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &, Single_list<T> const&);
};

template <typename Type>
Single_list<Type>::Single_list():
list_head( 0 ),
list_tail( 0 ),
node_count( 0 ) {
    // empty constructor
}

template <typename Type>
Single_list<Type>::Single_list( Single_list<Type> const &list ):
list_head( 0 ),
list_tail( 0 ),
node_count( 0 ) {

    Single_List<Type> *tmp_ptr = 0;

    for(tmp_ptr = head(); tmp_ptr !== 0; tmp_ptr->next()){
         //my copy constructor so far..
        tmp_ptr->retrieve() = list;
    }
}

template <typename Type>
Single_list<Type>::~Single_list() {

    Single_list<Type> *tmp_ptr = 0; //temp pointer initialized

    for(tmp_ptr = head(); tmp_ptr !==0; tmp_ptr-next()){
        //iterate through single_list, then delete
        delete tmp_ptr;
    }
}
```

Oh and the operator:

```
template <typename Type>
Single_list<Type> &Single_list<Type>::operator = (Single_list<Type> const &rhs) {
    Single_list<Type> copy( rhs );

    swap( copy );

    return *this;
```

Comment: By its own, it cannot be decided whether the implementation of a copy constructor is reasonable. Whether an implementation of the copy constructor is reasonable depends on 1) all class variables. 2) The destructor. 3) The copy assignement operator. On the other hand, you only asked whether it is possible. Yes, such an implementation as you have given is possible. But I seriously doubt that it is reasonable.

Comment: Ok thanks. So basically I can make a new temporary array thats the same size as the amount of nodes there are, set each cell of the array equal to the nodes, then set the array equal to list which is in the parameters? Am I right?

Comment: The part where I said that "*whether an implementation of the copy constructor is reasonable depends on 1) all class variables. 2) The destructor. 3) The copy assignement operator*" was a actually a hidden request to show 1) all class variables. 2) The destructor. 3) The copy assignement operator. Also, your comment must have overlapped with my edit, otherwise you surely would not have missed me saying "*But I seriously doubt that it is reasonable.*"

Comment: oh LOL okay so I should paste my code?

Comment: Please make sure to add a language tag to your questions; you'll get more attention and syntax highlighting.

Comment: (And if you answer a comment, add a `@` in front of the user name to notify that user ;) -- see [Comment Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting); [help])

Comment: @odius this is already implemented in the STL for C++0x and C++11. Just `#include <list>` and you can use it. If you're doing this to develop your coding skillz, then you may want to study the code that implements `std::list<>`

Comment: @axon okay so you're telling me that instead of writing a whole bunch of code, there is a shortcut key word I can use if I #include <list>?

Comment: @odius Yes. I've written it as an answer. Let me know if it's not what you need

Comment: @axon Oh okay I am not sure if I can use that but I will keep you updated. Thanks for all your help! Also I am starting to like this stack overflow :)

Comment: I dont think that would work for me, I need to do a deep copy apparently. I need to pass by value or something..

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here. Do you want to allocate the space for all nodes at once in the copy ctor? -- the Standard Library contains `std::list`, a class template for doubly-linked lists (with a O(1) element count) and `std::forward_list`, a class template for singly-linked lists (without a O(1) element count). Their copy-ctors do a "deep copy", i.e. the elements are copied. If the elements are of type pointer, that means each pointer will be copied (but not the object pointed to).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this to develop your coding skillz, then you may want to study the code that implements `std::list<>`. Otherwise, you can just use it.

The move constructor and move assignment operator `=` are already implemented in C++0x and C++11 in the Standard Template Library (STL). You can make use of them (with a compatible compiler) simply by including the appropriate header (`#include <list>`) and using it.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate:

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> my_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) // make a big list
        my_list.push_back(i);

    list<int> my_copied_list = my_list;       // copy the list using the conventional assignment operator (slow)
    list<int> my_moved_list  = move(my_list); // move the list using the move assignment operator (fast)
}
```